# Run script or command on Pi based on Alexa voice command or skill

Tags: remote

I'm building a power relay controller based on RPi and I want to be able to turn my whole system off by asking Alexa to shut it down.

I have considered using an Alexa-controlled "smart" relay to short the GPIO pins that send a shutdown command, but it would be simpler if I can launch a shutdown command/script/task on the Pi itself through an Alexa voice command.

Note: I'm not asking about the Alexa voice control libraries running on a Pi, I have external Echo devices that I would be talking to. The Pi in question will be connected to the Internet (or at least my home network) for monitoring/control purposes.

Comment: Hello. Maybe a combination of IFTTT + Alexa and some Python on your Pi? [Here's](http://kimondo.co.uk/ifttt-blinky-led-with-a-raspberry-pi/) a (very old) project that uses IFTTT to turn GPIOs on and off that you might be able to use as a starting point.

Comment: Please check my answer here: https://iot.stackexchange.com/a/4112/9008 You can apply it to running anything you want on your Raspberry Pi using the ecex node in node-red. It's not a straightforward solution, but it works.